# CSS Z-index for Background Images

Tags: css, z-index

I have two background images-a and b. Automaticly A is in front of B. Can I change this using Z-index?

Comment: Can you post the code ?

Comment: I will edit the orginal question with the code inside

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple background images...but the stacking order is determined by the order they are listed in your CSS.

```
background: 
   url(number.png) 600px 10px no-repeat,  /* On top, like z-index: 4; */
   url(thingy.png) 10px 10px no-repeat,   /* Middle like z-index: 3; */
   url(Paper-4.png);                      /* On bottom, like z-index: 1; */
```

[**CSS-Tricks Article**](http://css-tricks.com/stacking-order-of-multiple-backgrounds/)

Comment: So its depending on the order

Comment: Yes, which ever comes first is on top and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea because Z-index requires that the image is Absolutely positioned which can cause other layout problems in different browsers. it's better if you put the image in as a background image using CSS and transition for changing background. [Here](http://www.ehow.com/how_12132769_make-background-transition-css.html) you have a sample of background transition.